# Passed array as parameter and don't work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I have a JavaScript function with calls a picture gallery. I get the img's name in my DB with php, and trying to pass the results as a parameter to the js function, so it will load the imgs on my page. It should load 4 images, but he's assuming the values `<img src="img/array1array2array3array4" />`, when it should be `<img src="img/array1" />`, `<img src="img/array2" />`, and etc... How could i do it ? Here's my JS function:

```
function galerias(query){


        var imgs = document.querySelector("#gallery");
        var x = 1;

            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

        for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++){
            imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+query[i]+"'class='imgs-galeria'>";

             x++;
        }

        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "<a class='row' href='pics.html?gal="+x+"'><div class='twelve columns link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";

}
```

PHP DB query:

```
function consultarDados($query){
    $dbResult = array();
    $conexao = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
    mysql_select_db($this->banco, $conexao);
    $rs = mysql_query($query, $conexao);
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
            //array push insere valores do $rows ao final do array $dbResult
            array_push($dbResult, $rows);
        }
    return $dbResult;
    mysql_close($conexao);
}
```

This is how i made the query in the pictures page:

```
include 'connectDB.php';
$conexao = new connectDb();
$galeria_1= $conexao->consultarDados('select * from portfolio where gal= 1 and theme= 1');

$parametroGal = array();
foreach($galeria_1 as $result){

        array_push($parametroGal, $result['nome']);
    }
```

And how i pass the value as parameter to the JS function, on my `window.onload`:

```
<?php
        echo'galerias("'.$parametroGal.'");';
?>
```

This results:

```
<div class="eight columns">
    //that way it just give me as result the word array, since $parametroGal is an array
    <img src="img/A" class="imgs-galeria">
    <img src="img/r" class="imgs-galeria">
    <img src="img/r" class="imgs-galeria">
    <img src="img/a" class="imgs-galeria">
    <img src="img/y" class="imgs-galeria">
</div>

//i need to get the value of that array, like this:

<div class="eight columns">
    //the result of the array, the results of the query in the DB
    <img src="img/foto1_1.jpg" class="imgs-galeria">
    <img src="img/foto1_2.jpg" class="imgs-galeria">
    <img src="img/foto1_3.jpg" class="imgs-galeria">
    <img src="img/foto1_4.jpg" class="imgs-galeria">
</div>
```

Comment: It might actually work if you had some <script> tags in your echo.

Comment: In your javascript code, it doesn't look like you're using your 'query' parameter as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<?php
        echo'<script>galerias("'.implode("\",\"",$parametroGal).'");</script>';
?>
```

**Edited**

Comment: They might have already echoed out a script tag before that part of the php code

Comment: don't you thing explode is needed and loop is required. implode convert it in a string by combining all values and that is his problem.

Comment: @trixtur It's just the same, the function is working and the query is also working, but not properly. It's not bringing the pictures as it should. It is passing all array results as img src, and it should bring 4 img's tag with one array result in each.

Comment: `<img src="img/array1array2array3array4" />, ` he stated in first  some lines

Comment: yep I overlooked that.

Comment: @anuseranother I changed my code a little. If you use some "glue" you can split up your parameters.

Comment: Yup i come to know why you said that. i added an answer. Please try

Comment: @trixtur it just giver the result '<img src="img/array1" ,'array2,array3,array4'class="imgs-galeria">'